# SQL Server and NodeJS - Connection Pool availabilty is always zero

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I'm trying to initialize a pool of SQL Server connections for my nodejs web application to use. I've set the config to create 10 min connections but when I start the app with the below code. I only have 0 available connections which doesn't allow me to begin any transactions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**test.js**

```
const sql = require('mssql');
require('dotenv').config();

const appPool = new sql.ConnectionPool({
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PWD,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    server: process.env.DB_HOST,
    pool: {
        min: 10,
        max: 100,
        acquireTimeoutMillis: 15000,
    },
    options: {
        encrypt: true,
        trustServerCertificate: false
    }
});

appPool.connect().then(pool => {
    console.log(`SERVER: Connected to the db and ${pool.available} connections are available!`);
});
```

**Output**

```
MINGW64 ~/Desktop/React Projects/dummy-project (master)
$ node test.js
SERVER: Connected to the db and 0 connections are available!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`node-mssql` uses [tarn.js](https://github.com/vincit/tarn.js) for connection pooling. The connections are not created preemptively. Instead, they're created as and when the connections are requested. Once the number of concurrent requests for connections exceed `pool.min`, the available connections in the pool stays at that level.

So, doing a transaction or running a query shouldn't be a problem, node-mssql will create the connection and fulfil the request.

If you really want to have `pool.min` connections in your pool, you can write a small script to fire some concurrent queries on your database which will warm up the pool for you.